# Connecting 4 tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am only a beginner in SQL, and I have problem that I can not solve.

The problem is the following:

i have four tables

```
Student: matrnr, name, semester, start_date
Listening: matrnr<Student>, vorlnr<Subject>
Subject: vorlnr, title, sws, teacher<Professor>
Professor: persnr, name, rank, room
```

I need to list all the students that are listening the Subject of some Professor with samo name.

EDIT:

```
select s.* 
from Student s, Listening h
where s.matrnr=h.matrnr
and h.vorlnr in (select v.vorlnr from Subject v, Professor p                        
where v.gelesenvon=p.persnr and p.name='Kant');
```

This is how i solved it but i am not sure is it optimal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is good. Only, you want to show students, but join students with listings thus getting student-listing combinations.

Moreover you use a join syntax that is out-dated. It was replaced more than twenty years ago with explicit joins (INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, etc.)

You can do it with subqueries only:

```
select * 
from Students, 
where matrnr in 
(
  select matrnr
  from Listening
  where vorlnr in
  (
    select vorlnr 
    from Subject
    where gelesenvon in
    (
      select persnr
      from Professor
      where name='Kant'
    )
  )
);
```

Or join the other tables:

```
select * 
from Students 
where matrnr in 
(
  select l.matrnr
  from Listening l
  inner join Subject s on s.vorlnr = l.vorlnr
  inner join Professor p on p.persnr = s.gelesenvon and p.name='Kant'
);
```

Or with EXISTS:

```
select * 
from Students s 
where exists
(
  select *
  from Listening l
  inner join Subject su on su.vorlnr = l.vorlnr
  inner join Professor p on p.persnr = su.gelesenvon and p.name='Kant'
  where l.matrnr = s.matrnr
);
```

Some people like to join everthing and then clean up in the end using DISTINCT. This is easy to write, especially as you don't have to think your query through at first. But for the same reason it can get complicated when more tables and more logic are involved (like aggregations) and it can become quite hard to read, too.

```
select distinct s.* 
from Students s 
inner join Listening l on l.matrnr = s.matrnr
inner join Subject su on su.vorlnr = l.vorlnr
inner join Professor p on p.persnr = su.gelesenvon and p.name='Kant';
```

At last it is a matter of taste.

Comment: At the first look I would prefer the variant with EXISTS but as I see on Oracle both IN and EXISTS produce the same plan in this case.

Comment: @VDohnal: As it should, because IN and EXISTS do the same thing. Especially in Oracle, which even handles tuples like `where (a,b) in (select ...)` which many other dbms do not. And again it's a matter of taste whether to choose IN or EXISTS. I often choose IN; maybe because I tend to think in sets.

Comment: `IN` and `EXISTS` are very similar, however they are not the same - not only in terms of performance. You can get different results when your data contains `NULL` values. See some explanations here: [Understand how NULLs affect IN and EXISTS](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-how-nulls-affect-in-and-exists/) or google for `oracle difference in and exists null`

Comment: @Wernfried: You are right; NOT IN and NOT EXISTS treat null data differently. A rare case, but still something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

When you have an SQL problem, a good way of presenting the problem is to show us the tables as `CREATE TABLE` statements. Such statements show details such as the types of the columns and which columns are primary keys. Additionally this allows us to actually build a little database in order to reproduce a faulty behavior or just to test our solutions.

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    matrnr NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    name NVARCHAR2(50),
    semester NUMBER(2),
    start_date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE Listening
(
    matrnr NUMBER(9), -- Student
    vorlnr NUMBER(9), -- Subject
    CONSTRAINT PK_Listening PRIMARY KEY (matrnr, vorlnr)
);

CREATE TABLE Subject
(
    vorlnr NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    title NVARCHAR2(50),
    sws NVARCHAR2(50),
    teacher NUMBER(9) -- Professor
);

CREATE TABLE Professor
(
    persnr NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    name NVARCHAR2(50),
    rank NUMBER(3),
    room NVARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Using this schema, my solution would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Student
WHERE
    matrnr IN (
        SELECT L.matrnr
        FROM
            Listening L
            INNER JOIN Subject S
                ON L.vorlnr = S.vorlnr
            INNER JOIN Professor P
                ON S.teacher = P.persnr
        WHERE P.name = 'Kant'
    );
```

You can find it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5179dc/2
Since I didn't insert any records, the only thing it is testing is the syntax and the correct use of table and column names.

Your solution is suboptimal. It does not differentiate between joining of tables and additional conditions specified as where-clause. It can produce several result records per student if they attend several courses of the professor. Therefore my solution puts all the other tables into the sub-select.

Answer (score 2):

```
select st.name
from student st
join listening l on l.matrnr = st.matrnr
join subject su on su.vorlnr = l.vorlnr
join professor p on su.teacher = p.persnr
where p.name = 'some name'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM student 
INNER JOIN listening ON student.matrnr = listening.matrnr
INNER JOIN subject ON listening.vorlnr = subject.vorlnr
INNER JOIN professor ON subject.teacher = professor.name
WHERE professor.name = 'some name'
```